# Should I call .doOnComplete() on the observable or subscribe with a new Observer<>?

Tags: android, observable, rx-java, rx-java2, observers

I have a fairly simple logic I'm trying to implement. I have an audio tone that needs to complete playing before I start playing some sort of media content.

The audio tone I have is an observable. My current setup works, but I'm curious if I'm doing it the correct way.

This is what I have currently:

```
audioToneObservable
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .doOnComplete(() -> playMyFile())
     .subscribe();
```

Is this the correct way to achieve the flow I'm looking for? Or should my code look like this instead:

```
audioToneObservable
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .subscribe(new Observer<>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Integer integer) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
              playMyFile();
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
              playMyFile();
            }
          });
```

It works in both ways so I'm a bit confused if either of them are acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rx [**do**](https://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html)* operators allow you to inject a side effect behavior into your sequence.

So, if you want to encapsulate the call of `playMyFile()` you can use `doOnComplete()`, also it will be called before `onComplete()`.
But as I see you use `onError()` as well then in your case, it's better to use `doAfterTerminate()` it will replace both (`onComplete` and `onError`).

Comment: Thank you! I find it difficult to understand the documentation at times so i appreciate your answer! You mentioned `doOnComplete()` gets called before `onComplete()`. Does replacing it with `doAfterTerminate()` handle the case gracefully? I have to play the audio tone first and only once it finished playing I have to play the other file.

Comment: Yes, it will be invoke once in case of complete or error.